# Editing Docs custom metadata field in Publication Manager causes error

Tags: tridion-docs

I'm getting an error when editing a custom metadata field on a topic in Tridion Docs, via the Publication Manager interface and then saving an trying to reopen the topic (there is no similar issue in the web client interface). This custom metadata is connected from Tridion Sites to Tridion Docs (using a custom metadata binder). The error is fairly cryptic and the logs are not being much help:

```
Error loading the XML for the object "xmlFieldTags": An error occurred while parsing EntityName. Line 1, position 2513.
```

[image]

The full logs are as follows:

```
02:41:25.7026   Error   10  00008   a:UC:Damian API25/MetadataBinding/ResolveIds    Trisoft.InfoShare.API25.MetadataBinding.ResolveIds      []  
Trisoft.InfoShare.BorderControl.ErrorLoadingXMLException: Error loading the XML for the object "xmlFieldTags": An error occurred while parsing EntityName. Line 1, position 2513.
   at Trisoft.InfoShare.BorderControl.Schema.Validate(SchemaId schemaId, String objectName, String xml)
   at Trisoft.InfoShare.API25.MetadataBinding.ResolveIds(String xmlFieldTags, String language, String& outXmlFieldTags)
<no type>.SyncInvokeResolveIds => MetadataBinding.InfoShareWS.Wcf.API25.Interfaces.IMetadataBinding.ResolveIds => MetadataBinding.ResolveIds
02:41:25.7026   Error   10  00008   a:UC:Damian API25/MetadataBinding/ResolveIds    Trisoft.InfoShare.API25.MetadataBinding.ResolveIds  (xmlFieldTags=[<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<ishfieldtags xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <ishfieldtag ishfieldname="***************">
    <tags>
      <tag id="/webdav/035***************" />
    </tags>
  </ishfieldtag>
</ishfieldtags>])   []  
02:41:25.7026   Error   10  00008   a:UC:Damian API25/MetadataBinding/ResolveIds    Trisoft.InfoShare.API25.MetadataBinding.ResolveIds  (language=[])   []  
02:41:25.7026   Debug   10  00008   a:UC:Damian API25/MetadataBinding/ResolveIds    Trisoft.InfoShare.API25.MetadataBinding.ResolveIds()        [MethodExit(00291)] 1313ms
02:41:25.7026   Error   10  00008   a:UC:Damian API25/MetadataBinding/ResolveIds    InfoShareWS.Wcf.Base.WCFCustomization.SessionTransformerInvoker.System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.IOperationInvoker.Invoke     []  
Trisoft.InfoShare.API25.InfoShareException: Error loading the XML for the object "xmlFieldTags": An error occurred while parsing EntityName. Line 1, position 2513. [203;ErrorLoadingXML]
   at Trisoft.InfoShare.API25.MetadataBinding.ResolveIds(String xmlFieldTags, String language, String& outXmlFieldTags)
   at InfoShareWS.Wcf.API25.MetadataBinding.InfoShareWS.Wcf.API25.Interfaces.IMetadataBinding.ResolveIds(String xmlFieldTags, String language, String& outXmlFieldTags)
   at SyncInvokeResolveIds(Object , Object[] , Object[] )
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SyncMethodInvoker.Invoke(Object instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]& outputs)
   at InfoShareWS.Wcf.Base.WCFCustomization.SessionTransformerInvoker.System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.IOperationInvoker.Invoke(Object instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]& outputs)
ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5 => DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin => SessionTransformerInvoker.System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.IOperationInvoker.Invoke
02:41:25.7181   Error   10  00008   na::    API25/MetadataBinding/ResolveIds    InfoShareWS.Wcf.API25.ErrorHandlers.ErrorHandler.LogFaultContract   (InfoShareErrorNumber=[-203],Origin=[Trisoft.InfoShare.API25],Description=[Error loading the XML for the object "xmlFieldTags": An error occurred while parsing EntityName. Line 1, position 2513. [203;ErrorLoadingXML]])  []  
02:41:25.7181   Error   10  00008   na::    API25/MetadataBinding/ResolveIds    InfoShareWS.Wcf.API25.ErrorHandlers.ErrorHandler.LogFaultContract   (XMLDetail=[<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?><detail><errnumber>-203</errnumber><logger applicationname="InfoShareAuthor" userid="Damian" serverrequestid="8" serverhostname="ECL-US-TDCMF003"><logs><error logid="0" status="new" resourceid="ErrorLoadingXML" resourcelib="isAuthor" number="-203"><basedescription>Error loading the XML for the object "xmlFieldTags": An error occurred while parsing EntityName. Line 1, position 2513. [203;ErrorLoadingXML]</basedescription><desc>Error loading the XML for the object "xmlFieldTags": An error occurred while parsing EntityName. Line 1, position 2513. [203;ErrorLoadingXML]</desc><param paramname="object" paramtype="String">xmlFieldTags</param><param paramname="reason" paramtype="String">An error occurred while parsing EntityName. Line 1, position 2513.</param></error></logs></logger></detail>])    []
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It turns out this is caused by a '&' character in some of the keywords that are connected into Tridion Docs from Tridion Sites, even if that particular keywords is not in use - it may be involved in the ResolveIds method, where is causes an error since '&' is apparently invalid in XML - see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23541910/an-error-occurred-while-parsing-entityname-line1-position-844).

I was able to resolve this by removing the annotated labels from my custom metadata binder, as these are optional anyway (see [here](https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20Docs-v1.1.2#addHistory=true&filename=GUID-C7EA8F3E-1D49-4FF5-92D8-4EBBCDBCDC11.xml&docid=GUID-C7EA8F3E-1D49-4FF5-92D8-4EBBCDBCDC11&inner_id=&tid=342b3c9b-1948-4586-a2f3-4b8e3fb688d8&query=AnnotatedLabel&scope=&resource=&toc=false&eventType=lcContent.loadDocGUID-C7EA8F3E-1D49-4FF5-92D8-4EBBCDBCDC11&url=/LiveContent/web/search.xql%3Fc%3Dt%26pub%3DSDL+Tridion+Docs-v1.1.2%26lang%3Den-US%26action%3Dsearch%26query%3DAnnotatedLabel&sid=lcSearch.runSearch1569299885785&currentQuery=AnnotatedLabel&currentScope=) for reference).

I was able to get this working even with '&' character in my regular labels - it was only the annotated labels that causes issues.